# Detect which monitor shows the Window

Tags: java, windows, jframe, toolkit, multiple-monitors

I do have main application JFrame window which can include different components. I open a self implemented OnScreenKeyboard when the user select a editable textfield. The OSK is also a JFrame window.

When the user drag the main window to another monitor, the OSK should also be shown on the same monitor. For this i have to detect the monitor the main JFrame is shown.

I try to find a method in

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
```

but was not able to find someting.

Do you know how i can detect the monitor where a JFrame is shown?

Java-Version 1.4
Windows XP

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer, if the solution of all available monitors are the same.

For **AWT**:

Every Control does have the method getMonitor() from which the screen position get can calculated from like:

```
Monitor widgetMonitor = mTextWidget.getMonitor();
Rectangle monitorRect = widgetMonitor.getBounds();

if(monitorRect.x < 0){
   // shown in left monitor, starting from the main monitor
}

if(monitorRect.x > monitorRect.width){
   // shown in right monitor, starting from the main monitor
}
```

For **SWT**:

It is just a snip at my origial code. you should ask if return values are not null ans something like this!

```
    int monitorWidth = 0;
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices = ge.getScreenDevices();
    if(screenDevices.length > 0){
        monitorWidth = screenDevices[0].getDisplayMode().getWidth();
    }


    Point ownerLocationOnScreen = owner.getLocationOnScreen();

    int screenMovingX = 0;
    if(ownerLocationOnScreen.x < 0){
        screenMovingX = -monitorWidth;
    }
    if(ownerLocationOnScreen.x > monitorWidth){
        screenMovingX = monitorWidth;
    }
```